# How to get latest date that is not greater then record date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with names with eomonth history.
I need to join another table that has information about "tests" performed on names:

[image]

The result table should show the latest ID and date of performed test but the date of test cannot be greater than the data month:

[image]

Any ideas how to perform this?

Comment: So what have you tried? This looks like you just need a `WHERE`; which is a basic part of SQL.

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: I tried: 
WHERE EOMONTH >= TEST_DATE
this works for first test but not for second.
Last table is the expected result

Comment: @mandmi  . . . You have three columns with dates in your data and your question does not refer to them using those names.  I'm a bit lost on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you want the most recent `EOMONTH` from the second table for each row in the first table.  If that is the correct interpretation, then you can simply use `apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.test_id = t1.test_id and t2.eomonth <= t1.test_date
      order by t2.eomonth desc
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This join works perfectly:

```
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.name = b.name and a.eomonth >= b.id_date and a.eomonth < LAG(b.id_date,1,'3000-01-01') OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY b.id_date desc)
```